Smallest element after xor

Starting with array of N positive integers, support Q queries. Each query contains a positive integer i. To answer the query, replace each element of the array with the result of xoring it with i, then output the earliest index of the smallest element in the array. Each query changes the array.

I could only come up with O(N*Q). I try to think of range update data structure but xor can make number bigger so I don't think it's right way.
How to solve faster?
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> A(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++) {
        int i;
        cin >> i;
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            A[k] = A[k] ^ i;
        }
        int mini = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            if (A[k] < A[mini]) {
                mini = k;
            }
        }
        cout << mini << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}


Example input
5
1 2 3 4 5
3
1
2
6

Example output
0
2
4

Example output explanation
First query is 1. After xor array with 1, it becomes 0 3 2 5 4. Smallest number: index 0
Second query is 2. After xor previous array with 2, it becomes 2 1 0 7 6. Smallest number: index 2
Second query is 6. After xor previous array with 6, it becomes 4 7 6 1 0. Smallest number: index 4


https://cs.stackexchange.com is better suitable for looking for algorithms.

@user24714692 N and Q are at most 10 ^ 5.

@3CxEZiVlQ oh, am I mistaken about what algorithm tag here is for? I feel like you get better answers on stackoverflow

Stuff all your numbers in a suffix trie. That's simply a tree where the path through the tree (left, left, right ,.... ) encodes the bits of the number. The smallest number is, as usual, the number constructed by always going left. Xoring the entire array with a query for bit X means that on level X the subtree for 1 (or right) becomes the smallest, not 0. You can decide to swap all nodes on that level, or you can modify the tree traversal to take xors into consideration. That's O(N log N) construction and O(Q log N) lookup.

That last bit should be O(Q) lookup, since the number of bits is constant (but vague)

There's a possible solution with O(N×B) construction space, O(N×{B+logN}) setup time & O(Q) lookup time complexity. Where B=[log max(values)], or simply the bit depth. So the overall complexity won't be more than O(N×logN)+O(Q). Memory usage is contiguous; So, there will be very little likelihood of cache-misses for small enough data-sets. No need for exoteric data structures.

@Red.Wave can you explain your solution? and what's a exoteric data structure?

Taking the description literally, there is no way avoiding N*Q.

@user25680598 specifically, I mean no trie. It's simpler than that. Sort the indice, and keep the 2 indice for each bit - the first 0, and the first 1. Then keep an accumulated xor of all queries. The minimum value belongs to this later list.

@Red.Wave Im not following. the min value belongs to which list? could you write up an answer? im sure others will be interested in a simpler solution

Represent the elements in the array as fixed-width binary numbers (ie: sequences of 0 and 1 bits), most significant bit first. Construct a binary trie from them, storing the array index in the trie at the bottom.
If the fixed width is W, any single query can be answered in O(W) time; as you descend down the trie, if there's a single branch follow it, otherwise go down the "0" branch if the xor value has a "0" bit in that position, otherwise go with the "1" branch.
The intuition here is easy; if there's even one element in the array that has the same most significant bit as the xor value, the smallest element in the array must be one of those elements. And then so on for the next significant bit. The trie makes finding these sets efficient.
To run successive queries, instead of updating the datastructure, query against the running XOR of the queries so far. So if the queries are Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4..., then instead query Q1, Q1^Q2, Q1^Q2^Q3, Q1^Q2^Q3^Q4, ...
(where ^ is XOR). That means you don't have to update the trie at all.

... and instead of updating the trie for each query, accumulate the queries into updates that apply to the remaining queries.

@MattTimmermans ah yes, I'd missed that part of the question.

what do I do for updating the data structure?

@user25680598 Matt answered in a comment, but I updated my answer to make the answer more complete.

You can use segment tree, which is a common technique for querying arrays and lower the time complexity to O(N log N):

Link

Code
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SegmentTree
{
    int N;
    std::vector<int> A;
    std::vector<int> seg;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> tree;

    void build_tree(
        const int node,
        const int left,
        const int right)
    {
        if (left == right)
        {
            tree[node] = {A[left], left};
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            build_tree(2 * node + 1, left, mid);
            build_tree(2 * node + 2, mid + 1, right);
            tree[node] = std::min(tree[2 * node + 1], tree[2 * node + 2]);
        }
    }

    void update_xor(
        const int node,
        const int left,
        const int right)
    {
        if (seg[node] != 0)
        {
            tree[node].first ^= seg[node];
            if (left != right)
            {
                seg[2 * node + 1] ^= seg[node];
                seg[2 * node + 2] ^= seg[node];
            }
            seg[node] = 0;
        }
    }

    void update_tree(
        const int l,
        const int r,
        const int val,
        const int node,
        const int left,
        const int right)
    {
        update_xor(node, left, right);
        if (left > right || left > r || right < l)
            return;
        if (left >= l && right <= r)
        {
            seg[node] ^= val;
            update_xor(node, left, right);
            return;
        }
        const int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        update_tree(l, r, val, 2 * node + 1, left, mid);
        update_tree(l, r, val, 2 * node + 2, mid + 1, right);
        tree[node] = std::min(tree[2 * node + 1], tree[2 * node + 2]);
    }

    std::pair<int, int> get_min(
        const int l,
        const int r,
        const int node,
        const int left,
        const int right)
    {
        update_xor(node, left, right);
        if (left > right || left > r || right < l)
            return {INT_MAX, -1};
        if (left >= l && right <= r)
            return tree[node];
        const int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        return std::min(
            get_min(l, r, 2 * node + 1, left, mid),
            get_min(l, r, 2 * node + 2, mid + 1, right));
    }

    SegmentTree(const std::vector<int> &nums) : A(nums)
    {
        N = std::size(A);
        tree.resize(4 * N);
        seg.resize(4 * N, 0);
        build_tree(0, 0, N - 1);
    }

    void update(const int l, const int r, const int val)
    {
        update_tree(l, r, val, 0, 0, N - 1);
    }

    std::pair<int, int> query(const int l, const int r)
    {
        return get_min(l, r, 0, 0, N - 1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> Q = {1, 2, 6};
    for (auto &q : Q)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < std::size(A); ++i)
            A[i] ^= q;
        SegmentTree seg_tree(A);
        std::pair<int, int> res = seg_tree.query(0, std::size(A) - 1);
        std::cout << res.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

Prints
0
2
4


This is also O(NQ) with an even worse constant factor.

don't you still have a loop N times for each query? how is this any better
